# MAAS Failed deploying Connection refused when downloading root-tgz

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, maas, wget

I have a problem with MAAS node deployment. I commission the node and it all goes well, node shuts down and node is in ready status. I start the node it goes to Deploying state and when it starts to download root-tgz file it get's to 34% and I get the message Connection reset by the peer.

The message looks like:

Read error at byte 110815170/328093608 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

--2015-10-15 11:39:00-- (try: 2) http://10.0.0.1/MAAS/static/images/ubuntu/amd64/generic/trusty/release/root-tgz
Connection to 10.0.0.1:80 failed.Connection refused.

gzip stdin: unexpected end of file

tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Unexpected error while running command.
Command: [\'sh\', \'-cf\', \'wget "$1" --progress=dot:mega -0 - |tar -C "$2" --xattrs --xattrs -include=* -Sxpzf - --numeric-owner\', \'--\', \'http://10.0.0.1/MAAS/static/images/ubuntu/amd64/generic/trusty/release/root-tgz\', \'/tmp/tmp70Ffz8/target\']
Exit code: 2

Comment: Anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a network error.  Have you tried a second time?  You can always save the Ethernet MAC address, delete the node, create the node again using the same MAC address and watch it go through the motions again.

Comment: I have tried multiple times and it's always stuck at the same percentage. I can wget the file from other nodes that are deployed without any error. So it's only happening to nodes that are deploying which is strange.

Comment: Assuming that you could begin a pull of the root-tgz download from another node using that URL (acknowledging that 10.0.0.1 is listening on port 80 and the path is valid) then if it were me I'd ssh to the problem node and see if I could then manually (as the ubuntu user) also try to pull from that URL.  And then finally, I think I would delete the node, erase the hard disk manually, recreate it using a new node name and give that a try (on the assumption that the DHCP/DNS has re-issued the same IP address to two different nodes).

Comment: Done all of that and nothing. Also you cant ssh to the node that is in deployment since there is no root directory there. I wish I could do that because it would be easier to debug the situation.

Comment: I was able to deploy the node with debian installer. Fast installer is for some reason buggy while debian installer works like a charm. Now the problem is that for some reason public ssh key is not added to the node and I can't ssh to it because it asks for password.

Comment: Regarding the password prompt, it should ask for the passphrase that you used to secure the keypair (rather than the password).  You'd do "ssh ubuntu@nodename.domain" and then if your .ssh/known_hosts is happy it will prompt for the passphrase to decrypt the associated lines from that file.

Comment: Yeah, it should be a password less login, but I think the public key from the maas server is not injected to the node which is strange. I also changed the preseed file to add a password and I still couldn't login. I'm resolving this today, and then it comes the pain of creating a raid via preseed file.

Comment: If you install a monitor and watch the commissioning/deployment you'll see that it does seem to push the public key(s) to each node.  I'm just not sure if it does so in such a way that it satisfies the password-less login.

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding new ssh keys. I couldn't login to existing nodes after that of course but I have sorted that with a live cd and chroot in a way that I have changed default user password and changed ssh to password login instead of key based login. After that I have changed the authorized keys, removed the password from the default user and enabled key based login back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question since I have discovered that fast installer probably has a bug and debian installer goes through the process of installation without a problem.